# How can I improve this algorithm that solves for a missing coordinate?

Tags: java, if-statement, plot, split, coordinates

The user inputs 3 space separated coordinates that can make up a rectangle in the xy-plane. The algorithm returns what must be the 4th point to form a rectangle.

Example: "5 5", "5 7", and "7 5", newline separated, should return "7 7".

The below algorithm works for the provided test cases, but I am failing other cases, and I can't figure out why. Can anyone suggest a way to make my algorithm include all possible inputs - assuming that the 3 inputs provided do in fact form 3 corners of a rectangle?

```
import java.io.*;

public class cetvrta {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String point1 = reader.readLine(); // 5 5
        String point2 = reader.readLine(); // 5 7
        String point3 = reader.readLine(); // 7 5
        String[] cord1 = point1.split(" "); // ["5","5"]
        String[] cord2 = point2.split(" "); // ["5", "7"]
        String[] cord3 = point3.split(" "); // ["7", "5"]
        int x4 = 0;
        int y4 = 0;
        int x1 = Integer.parseInt(cord1[0]); // 5
        int y1 = Integer.parseInt(cord1[1]); // 5
        int x2 = Integer.parseInt(cord2[0]);
        int y2 = Integer.parseInt(cord2[1]);
        int x3 = Integer.parseInt(cord3[0]);
        int y3 = Integer.parseInt(cord3[1]);

        if (y1 == y2) {
            if (x3 == x1) {
                x4 = x2;
                y4 = y3;
            }
            if (x3 == x2) {
                x4 = x1;
                y4 = y3;
            }
        }
        if (y3 == y2) {
            if (x2 == x3) {
                x4 = x1;
                y4 = y2;
            }
            if (x2 == x1) {
                x4 = x3;
                y4 = y2;
            }
        }
        if (y1 == y3) {
            if (x2 == x1) {
                x4 = x3;
                y4 = y2;
            }
            if (x2 == x3) {
                x4 = x1;
                y4 = y2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(x4 + " " + y4);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird, rethink that:

```
if (y3 == y2) {
    if (x2 == x3) { // <---
        x4 = x1; // <---
        y4 = y2; // <---
    }
    if (x2 == x1) {
        x4 = x3;
        y4 = y2; // <---
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no hard and fast rule that "x-coordinates of 2 points of a rectangle has to match and so do the y-coordinates". Consider the image below for better understanding.

We can see that no two points have same x and y coordinates although there exists a perfect rectangle:
[image]

**Fix:**
I would recommend you to slightly change the algorithm as to proceed in the following way. Given the three points, find the point that isn't the corner(the one that does not pass through diagonal based out of other 2 points). From this point, calculate the slope to remaining points and assuming the 4th corner to be (x,y); draw out 2 locii. to satisfy slope1 * slope 2=-1. These 2 locii solved together will give the 4th point.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use basic vector algebra to resolve this task:

1. calculate vectors between the three known points
2. define which point of the given three is a vertex of right angle (90°) - if any
   this can be done using the fact that the scalar product of two perpendicular vectors is 0: `v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.0 == 0`
3. find the fourth point by adding to the right angle vertex two vectors outgoing from this vertex to the other two known points.

Sample implementation could look like this:

```java
// auxiliary classes
class Point {
    int x, y;
    
    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    
    Point add(Vector v) {
        return new Point(this.x + v.x, this.y + v.y);
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%d, %d)", x, y);
    }
}

class Vector {
    int x, y;
    
    Vector(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    Vector(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this(p2.x - p1.x, p2.y - p1.y);
    }
    
    static boolean isRightAngle(Vector v1, Vector v2) {
        return 0 == (v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y);
    }
    
    Vector add(Vector v) {
        return new Vector(this.x + v.x, this.y + v.y);
    }
}
```

Method to find the right angle vertex:

```java
static int rightAngleVertexIndex(Point ... p) {
    assert p.length == 3;
    Vector v01 = new Vector(p[0], p[1]);
    Vector v12 = new Vector(p[1], p[2]);
    Vector v20 = new Vector(p[2], p[0]);
    
    if (Vector.isRightAngle(v01, v12)) {
        return 1;
    } else if (Vector.isRightAngle(v12, v20)) {
        return 2;
    } else if (Vector.isRightAngle(v20, v01)) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Method to find the 4th point of rectangle (return `null` if no rectangle is possible):

```java
static Point findFourthVertex(Point ... points) {
    assert points.length == 3;

    final int[][] otherVertices = {
        {1, 2},
        {0, 2},
        {0, 1},
    };

    Point result = null;    
    int rightAngleIx = rightAngleVertexIndex(points);
    if (rightAngleIx != -1) {
        Point rightAngle = points[rightAngleIx];
        Point p1 = points[otherVertices[rightAngleIx][0]];
        Point p2 = points[otherVertices[rightAngleIx][1]];
        
        result = rightAngle.add(new Vector(rightAngle, p1).add(new Vector(rightAngle, p2)));
        System.out.println("The fourth vertex of the rectangle: " + result);
    } else {
        System.out.println("No right angle found between any of the points " + Arrays.toString(points));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Test:

```java
findFourthVertex(new Point(1, 1), new Point(5, 1), new Point(1, 4));
findFourthVertex(new Point(-1, -1), new Point(5, 0), new Point(6, 5));
```

Output:

```
The fourth vertex of the rectangle: (5, 4)
No right angle found between any of the points [(-1, -1), (5, 0), (6, 5)]
```